Probability of making a pair when 5 of 7 cards are known.
Five cards of different ranks are drawn from a standard deck. What is the probability of making exactly one pair by drawing two more cards?
It seems like it would be $$\frac{{5 \choose 1}\times{3 \choose 1}\times{8 \choose 1}\times{4 \choose 1} + {8 \choose 1}\times{4 \choose 2}}{47 \choose 2}$$
My thinking is there are two scenarios:

Match one of the existing five ranks with one of the other three cards of that rank and one of the four cards from one of the remaining eight ranks.
Make a pair with two of the four cards of the other eight ranks.

However, that seems to be overcounting the number of ways to make the pair. I expect an answer around 40%. Where have I made an error?

What makes you think your answer is wrong? Did you run some simulation?

Suppose that by drawing two more cards, you not only get a pair but also complete a flush.  Does that count as a pair for your purpose?

Assume for simplicity that the ranks are $1,2,\dots,13$, and the first five you've drawn are $A:=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.
Let $X_1$ be the first drawn card after that and $X_2$ be the second. There are various ways to make exactly one pair:
(a) $X_1\in A$ and $X_2\notin A$;
(b) $X_2\in A$ and $X_1\notin A$;
(c) $X_1=X_2$ and $X_1\notin A$.
Since these possibilities are disjoint, the probability of the union of them is the sum of probabilities (and the probabilities of (a) and (b) are the same):
$$
2\frac{(5\times 3)\cdot (8\times4)}{47\cdot 46}+\frac{(8\times 4)\cdot 3}{47\cdot 46}=0.4884...
$$
as there are 3 cards of the same rank for each $i\in A$ and there are $(13-5)$ remaining ranks with 4 cards each.
